# What is the simplest way to extract all 26 tables from a single DynamoDB db into AWS Glue Catalog

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue, amazon-athena, aws-glue-data-catalog

I am trying to build AWS QuickSight reports using AWS Athena that builds the specific views for said reports.  however, I seem to only be able to select a single table in creating the Glue job despite being able to select all tables i need for the crawler of the entire DB from Dynamo.
What is the simplest route to get a complete extract of all tables that is queryable in Athena.

I dont want to connect the reports direct to dynamoDB as it s a production database and want to create some separation to avoid any performance degradation by a poor query etc.